# Appending Access Token to FQL Query

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, access-token

Is there a way to append my long term access token to the query given at [Getting Facebook Events using fql](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10902259/getting-facebook-events-using-fql) ? The query at that link is

```
fql?q={"event_info":"SELECT name,description, pic_small,pic_big, eid,venue,location from event WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())", "event_venue":"SELECT name, username, page_id, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #event_info)"}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance...

**UPDATE** - The answer provided worked like a charm. THANK YOU!

Comment: If the answer worked, mark the answer as accepted please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Try this:

```
/fql?q=QUERY&access_token=TOKEN
```